# Problem in finding code for Simple image classification between two classes in android studio

Tags: python, android-studio, tensorflow-lite

i trained keras model on 2 classes and converted it into the .tflite model. now i want to use this model in android studio for simple classification between two classes when i put an image from the gallery. i can't find any help on internet regarding this simple way. On internet there is ways for camera but i don't need that in my simple project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use TensorFlow Lite's Java API to run inference on-device. Start with the [Android quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android), if you haven't installed the dependencies etc.

If your model is similar to how standard image classification models (for eg MobileNet) work, you can start with the [TFLite Image Classification app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android) source for inspiration. Specifically, you might be interested in the [Classifier base-class](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java) (and its [floating point](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/ClassifierFloatMobileNet.java) child class). Classifier demonstrates how you can use TFLite's Java API to instantiate a new Interpreter & run inference for image inputs.